# Upload image multipart in almofire swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have following data format to upload with image.I have problem in encoding string array plus I have also bool data with dictionary.

**Post Dictionary**

["title": title, "desription": description, "privacy": public, "status": true, "ids":["1","2","3"]]

**My coding:**

```
    Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in

        if let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(multiPartParams?["image"] as! UIImage , 0.5) {
            multipartFormData.append(imageData, withName: multiPartParams?["parameter"] as! String, fileName: "image.jpg", mimeType:  "image/jpeg")
        }
        if params != nil {
            for (key, value) in params! {
                multipartFormData.append(((value  as AnyObject).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue))!, withName: key)
            }}}, to: url, method: .post, headers: DataHandler.sharedInstance.getHeader(contentType: false),
            encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in

                switch encodingResult {

                case .success(let upload, _, _):
                    upload.responseJSON { response in

                        guard response.result.error == nil else { // error for eg : network unavailable
                            completion(nil, response.result.error as NSError?)
                            return;
                        }

                        let reponseObject = response.result.value as? [String:AnyObject?]

                        guard reponseObject != nil else { // reponse is nil
                            let error = NSError(domain: "No Data",
                                                code: 404,
                                                userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey : "No Data Returned"])
                            completion(nil, error)

                            return;
                        }


                        if (reponseObject![ResponseKey.success.rawValue] as? [String : AnyObject]) != nil { // Successfully get response
                            debugPrint( reponseObject)

                            completion(reponseObject![ResponseKey.success.rawValue]??[ResponseKey.data.rawValue]! as AnyObject?, nil)

                        } else if (reponseObject![ResponseKey.error.rawValue] as? [String : AnyObject]) != nil { //server  error

                            let responseData = Mapper<Response>().map(JSON: reponseObject![ResponseKey.error.rawValue]  as! [String : AnyObject])

                            let error = NSError(domain: "",
                                                code: (responseData?.code)!,
                                                userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey : (responseData?.message?[0])! as String])

                            completion(nil, error)

                        }
                    }
                case .failure(let encodingError):
                    completion(nil, encodingError as NSError?)

                    print("error:\(encodingError)")
                }
    })

}
```

Comment: Is `params` refers to `["title": title, "desription": description, "privacy": public, "status": true, "ids":["1","2","3"]]`?

Comment: yes params refers to  ["title": title, "desription": description, "privacy": public, "status": true, "ids":["1","2","3"]] and multiPartParams include image and image parameter

Comment: What error/log do you have?

Comment: its crash on       multipartFormData.append(((value  as AnyObject).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue))!, withName: key)

Comment: `String.Encoding.utf8` is only applicable for `String`, it cannot encode Bool and Array.